# Access Docusign-php-client

Tags: php, client, docusignapi

I had success setup the Docusign-php-client with everything working!

But how can I access the api directly?

I can only use public/index.php page to test all the samples,

how can I create my own page or own api call?

Is there any simple sample? sorry I‘m newbie on program, please help, thanks!

Comment: It's always good to ask, but stackoverflow is meant to solve programming questions and not a forum to find example applications. Though you will find plenty iexamples and information on the internet if you google "docusign-php-client examples"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what you already did since you didn't share code, but I would suggest you start by using https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php which is a repo with full working code and a PHP app using the DocuSign PHP library/SDK.
Try to use it and see how it work as a means of jump-starting your development.
You can then either modify it to fit your needs or copy/paste relevant pieces of code into your app.

Answer (score 1):

They are 31 PHP examples in here -> https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php. DocuSign php client is just an API wrapper. If you need more info you can visit https://developers.docusign.com/ for more info